# notification.setLatestEventInfoのシンボルが見つからないためコンパイルできない

Tags: android, java

ノーティフィケーションを表示するプログラムを作っているのですが `notification.setLatestEventInfo`の部分がシンボルが見つからないためコンパイルできません。

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class screen2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://www.google.com/";
        Uri uri= Uri.parse( url );

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationManager nManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification();

        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


        notification.tickerText = "テキスト";

        // この部分のシンボルが見つからないためコンパイルできない
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "タイトル",
                "メッセージ",
                pendingIntent
        );


        nManager.notify(1,notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: [cannot Resolve Method setLatestEventInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345768/cannot-resolve-method-setlatesteventinfo)

Answer (score 5):

`Notification` については、[日本語のドキュメント](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?hl=ja)が存在しますので、まずはそちらを参照してみてください。

バージョンごとに通知スタイルの追加や変更が行われ、それに伴い API も大きく変更が加えられてきました。`setLatestEventInfo()` は非常にレガシーな方法で、長らく廃止メソッドになっていましたが、APIレベル23（Android Marshmallow）で削除されました。

このようなバージョンによる API の差異を吸収するために、サポートライブラリに `NotificationCompat` が用意されています。最新の SDK バージョンにしか対応しないなどの稀なケースを除いては、基本的にはこちらを使用してみてください。

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("http", "www.google.com", null));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("content text")
        .setTicker("ticker text")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notify_icon))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();

manager.notify(0, notification);
```